# Is Gouvêa-Mazur's "Infinite Fern" a fractal?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, fractals

[EDIT]: Following Qiaochu Yuan's comment, it is better to clarify that *I do not know what the right definition of a fractal in the following question should be*. But a nice answer might contain such a definition. Moreover, a nice comment by Joël correctly points out that choosing which theory of rigid analytic spaces one wants to consider is crucial for my question which is otherwise ill-posed (but, again, I am more than happy if someone has an answer using *whichever theory* she prefers).

The *infinite fern* of Gouvêa-Mazur, introduced (I guess) in the paper by Barry Mazur  ["An "infinite fern" in the universal deformation space of Galois representations"](http://www.raco.cat/index.php/CollectaneaMathematica/article/download/56382/66675)  is a subset of the space attached to a universal deformation ring to a certain $\mod{p}$ Galois representation and which consists of infinitely many paths crossing at infinitely many points (there is a picture on page 36 of Mazur's paper) and given that this infinitely many crossing are dense in each path (they roughly correspond to integers in a $p$-adic disk) it seems to me that the above set could naturally be regarded as having some fractal behaviour. So, my questions are: is this the case? If yes, are there any results or conjectures on its fractal dimension, or connections between its fractal structure and some arithmetic of $p$-adic families of modular forms?

Comment: What does "is a fractal" mean here? 

Comment: @Qiaochu: Well, good point. I do not know and it seems to me - as non-expert!- that in general there is no such a uniquely agreed definition. Most probably, I am thinking at something like "if you cut a piece of the infinite fern into $n$ equal pieces, each looks like $1/m$-th of the original piece with `$n/m\notin\mathbb{Z}$`", but I am more than happy if the answer contains a precise definition ;-)

Comment: A possibility for a definition of "fractal" is "metric space with fractionary Hausdorff dimension".

Comment: @Qfwfq - I don't think that's a good definition of fractal, there are metric spaces, even subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which have integer Hausdorff dimension and are quintessentially fractal. See my comment here for an example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56677/what-notions-are-used-but-not-clearly-defined-in-modern-mathematics/56779#56779 (there's a typo, should be side length 1/4 rather than 1/2).

Comment: OK, is that space a metric space in a standard way?

Comment: I think the question is interesting, but somehow is still not well-posed. There is the problem of what is a fractal, discussed in earlier comments, but also the problem of what is the "infinite fern". I mean, it is a rigid analytic varieties, but there are at least three ways to formalize this notion, Tate's and Berkovich's and Huber's. Each leads to a different space..

Comment: connections between modular forms and fractals are explored in 

http://www.linas.org/math/sl2z.html



Comment: @Joël: very good point. What I had in mind was Tate's approach, but now that you mention it, Berkovich seems somehow much more natural for this kind of question. I guess thinking a bit more is appropriate, I will try to re-cast it "soon".
@ Carlo: thanks, I'll have a look!

Comment: @ Gerald: Well, yes and no. As Joël points out correctly in his comment, there are several structures of a rigid analytic space you can put on it, each giving you a different space. But on the other hand, the most "classical" approach (due to Tate) indeed endows the set of points with the structure of a non-archimedean metric space.

Comment: Qfwfq: A bit better definition of a fractal is "A metric space whose topological dimension is strictly less than its Hausdorff dimension". (Note that, a curve can have Hausdorff dimension 2.) One can also impose a "self-similarity" requirement, say, that there exists a constant $C$ so that for every two metric balls $B(x,r), B(y,R)$ in the space, if we rescale the metric on the former by $R/r$, it becomes $C$-bilipschitz to the latter. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this as an auto-answer mainly not to leave the question open.

After googling a bit better, I discovered two recent works by M. Lapidus and L. Hung (both available on  [Lapidus' webpage](http://math.ucr.edu/~lapidus/#FFIRG) )

- “Nonarchimedean Cantor Set and
  String”, Journal of Fixed Point
  Theory and Applications 3 (2008), pp.
  181-190, (Special issue
  dedicated to Vladimir Arnold on the
  occasion of his Jubilee. Vol. I.)
- “Self-Similar $p$-Adic Fractal Strings
  and Their Complex Dimensions”, $p$-Adic
  Numbers, Ultrametric Analysis and
  Applications (Russian Academy of
  Sciences, Moscow, and
  Springer-Verlag), No. 2, 1 (2009),
  pp. 167-180.

which seem to pose a "good" definition for a $p$-adic fractal. The definition follows the usual self-similarity one, attaching to each family $\{\Phi_1,\dots,\Phi_n\}$ of similarity contractions
$$
\Phi_j:\mathbb{Z}_p\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p
$$
the unique non-empy, compact, fixed subset $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $\mathcal{S}=\Phi_j(\mathcal{S})$ for each $1\leq j\leq n$. They develop some theory for such objects and define its Minkowsy dimension, mainly following the  box-counting dimension definition . In a closing remark of the second paper, they also say that "it would be interesting to generalize this theory from subspaces of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to Berkovich spaces" but I was unable to find anything more on the subject.